# Erase windows 8.1 installation

Tags: 14.04, windows, secure-erase

My primary operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 lts and then I installed windows 8.1 in another partition. Now, I don't need longer windows installation. Can I just erase the windows files and reformat my harddisk to linux format? Because I can't put my file in NTFS format.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just fine, as long as removing the partition does not break grub. If you do break grub you can use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a live cd/usb to fix it. Just make sure you only format the partition, do not delete it. I would recommend gparted as it has an extremely intuitive interface.